# Azure templates: Dynamically output all items created in CopyIndex() iteration

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

Taking the following simple template:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
  },
  "variables": {
    "nicName": "TESTNIC-",
    "ipConfigName": "ipconfig",
    "subnetRef": "/subscriptions/90a34ad-46aa-01a3-a3d4-223ac11bd6b3/resourceGroups/aResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/aVirtualNetwork/subnets/subnet-032"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2017-03-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
      "name": "[concat(variables('nicName'),copyIndex())]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "[concat(variables('nicName'),copyIndex())]"
      },
      "dependsOn": [],
      "copy": {
        "count": 2,
        "name": "nicLoop"
      },
      "properties": {
        "ipConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "[variables('ipconfigName')]",
            "properties": {
              "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
              "subnet": {
                "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "oNic": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[concat(variables('nicName'),0)]"
      //"value": "[resourceGroup().name]"
    }
  }
}
```

As copyIndex() is not allowed in `outputs.oNIC.value`, how do I output all networkInterfaces created in the copy, without specifically naming them?

In the above template, I have specified two nics, but in reality, there will be other resource types and I don't know how many there will be.

Even being able to return all instances of `/networkInterfaces` in a given resource would be a step in the right direction but I can't even seem to do that:

```
"outputs": {
  "oNic": {
    "type": "object",
    "value": "[reference(concat(resourceGroup().id,'Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces'))]"
  }
}
```

or

```
"outputs": {
  "oNic": {
    "type": "object",
    "value": "[reference('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces')]"
  }
}
```

I'm at a loss on this one.
TIA

### **Update: reasoning:**

As brief as possible: Part of the IP address is in the VMs hostname (client requirement), so the name of the VM is generated at deploy time. The template hierarchy looks something like:

```
#Deploy VM
DeployVM.json
    └ createNIC.json
        └ CreateVM.json
            └ createDataDisks.json

#Configure VM
ConfigureVM.json
```

CreateDataDisks actual template is "written out" by powershell (due to complexities of different types of data disks)

In order to simplify things (believe it or not), I have split the deployment into two separate deployment calls from PowerShell / VSTS / RunBook. The first actually deploys the VM(s) and the second configures it, using DSC and customScriptExtension resources. A complete deployment may have multiple servers with different roles, such as DB, WEB, client, although one set of templates / call will deploy only one role. A complete powershell script might look like:

```
$oDeploy = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -TemplateFile deployDatabase.json -role "Database" -Quantity 1
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -TemplateFile configureDatabase.json -role "Database" -VMName $oDeploy.vmNames

$oDeploy = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -TemplateFile deployWeb.json -role "Web" -Quantity 4
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -TemplateFile configureWeb.json -role "Web" -VMName $oDeploy.vmNames

$oDeploy = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -TemplateFile deployClientTypeA.json -role "ClientTypeA" -Quantity 1
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -TemplateFile configureClientTypeA.json -role "ClientTypeA" -VMName $oDeploy.vmNames

$oDeploy = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -TemplateFile deployClientTypeB.json -role "ClientTypeB" -Quantity 2
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -TemplateFile configureClientTypeB.json -role "ClientTypeB" -VMName $oDeploy.vmNames
```

Although I might have to do something like this, unless I can use CopyIndex to iterate over an array within the template (which I think I can. Just putting it out there):

```
$oDeploy = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -TemplateFile deployWeb.json -role "Web" -Quantity 4
foreach($vm in $oDeploy.vm)
{
    New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -TemplateFile configureWeb.json -role "Web" -VMName $vm
}
```

Good plan (I thought) until realising that I couldn't get all the VM names out of deploy{Role}.json to pass to configure{role}.json.

The other problem is to do with these pesky datadisks. The idea is that the deployment can be rerun with modifications / additions , so perhaps the first run creates three data disks, whereas the second one creates a fourth data disk. The real issue is with keeping the LUN ID unique. On the first deployment run, it starts at zero and increments to 2. On the second run, it again starts at zero, but zero is already taken. What I need to be able to do is sum the total number of datadisk resources and offset the count (by three) so on the second run, the LUN ID starts at two. There is no way that I know of to sum the number of resources in pure templates, so I use powershell, *but* as there may be more that one VM with multiple datadisks, I need to target the specific VM, which I need the name for, which needs to be outputted from the parent template, so powershell can pick it up and use it.

Comment: maybe lets take a step back, why would you need that output?

Comment: Added an update for the reasoning behind my madness. Be gentle.

Comment: are you willing to talk about this for a bit?

Comment: Certainly. Does SO have a PM facility then?

Comment: not that I'm aware of. but I was thinking about something like skype? because its a lot of typing otherwise ;)

Comment: Sent you an email with my skype details. Hope it's the right email.

Comment: replied to the email ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i can assure you - your question won't get a reasonable answer ;) but i see a few things that I'd like to poke quickly.

1. Data disks, I don't think that any combination of data disks cannot be created in the template. Also, if you want to add 1 disk to the existing vm you have to create a template holding all the previous disks and the new one (if you just create a template holding only the new disk all the old disks will get detached).
2. Why do you have 4 levels of template for nothing? That what you described can be done in a flat template
3. I don't know the reasoning behind different template for different role, but there might be some cases where this makes sense, although its hard to imagine such a case.
4. It looks like you could benefit from config files in your templates\deployments, but what you currently describe `There is no way that I know of to sum the number of resources in pure templates` sounds pretty weird. You need to add a disk to a specific vm but don't know anything about anything in the environment. :)

To me this whole deal looks strange. Everything seems a bit off ;)